# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_context') using tRPC with getUserFiles in React component

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma, trpc

I'm encountering an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_context')" when using the getUserFiles procedure from my tRPC client within a React component. I should be able to get the correct type for my data but it gives "any". The error occurs on my Dashboard, specifically, on my const { data: files, isLoading } = trpc.getUserFiles.useQuery();

Prisma schema where I define my files

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider  = "postgresql"
  url       = env("DATABASE_URL")
  directUrl = env("DIRECT_URL")
}

model User {
  id    String @id @unique
  email String @unique

  File File[]

  stripeCustomerId       String?   @unique @map(name: "stripe_customer_id")
  stripeSubscriptionId   String?   @unique @map(name: "stripe_subscription_id")
  stripePriceId          String?   @map(name: "stripe_price_id")
  stripeCurrentPeriodEnd DateTime? @map(name: "stripe_current_period_end")
}

enum UploadStatus {
  PENDING
  PROCESSING
  FAILED
  SUCCESS
}

model File {
  id   String @id @default(cuid())
  name String

  uploadStatus UploadStatus @default(PENDING)
  url          String
  key          String

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  User   User?   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String?
}
```

Here's my getUserFiles

```
import { db } from "@/db";
import { getKindeServerSession } from "@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server";
import { TRPCError } from "@trpc/server";
import { privateProcedure, publicProcedure, router } from "./trpc";

export const appRouter = router({
  authCallback: publicProcedure.query(async () => {
    // Get the user from the KindeServer session
    const { getUser } = getKindeServerSession();
    const user = await getUser();

    // If the user is not authenticated, throw an error
    if (!user || !user.id || !user.email)
      throw new TRPCError({ code: "UNAUTHORIZED" });

    // check if the user is in the database
    const dbUser = await db.user.findFirst({
      where: {
        id: user.id,
      },
    });

    if (!dbUser) {
      // create user in db
      await db.user.create({
        data: {
          id: user.id,
          email: user.email,
        },
      });
    }

    // Check if user exists in the database
    return { success: true };
  }),

  // Get user files from the database
  getUserFiles: privateProcedure.query(async ({ ctx }) => {
    // Extract the user ID from the context
    const { userId } = ctx;

    // Query the database for files belonging to the user
    return await db.file.findMany({
      where: {
        userId,
      },
    });
  }),
});

export type AppRouter = typeof appRouter;
```

Here's my private procedure

```
import { getKindeServerSession } from "@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server";
import { TRPCError, initTRPC } from "@trpc/server";

const t = initTRPC.create();
const middleware = t.middleware;

const isAuth = middleware(async (opts) => {
  const { getUser } = getKindeServerSession();
  const user = await getUser();

  if (!user || !user.id) {
    throw new TRPCError({ code: "UNAUTHORIZED" });
  }

  return opts.next({
    ctx: {
      userId: user.id,
      user,
    },
  });
});

export const router = t.router;
export const publicProcedure = t.procedure;
export const privateProcedure = t.procedure.use(isAuth);
```

Here's where the error occurs

```
import { trpc } from "@/app/_trpc/client";
import UploadButton from "./UploadButton";
import { Ghost } from "lucide-react";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const { data: files, isLoading } = trpc.getUserFiles.useQuery();

  return (
    <main className="mx-auto max-w-7xl md:p-10">
      <div className="mt-8 flex flex-col items-start justify-between gap-4 border-b border-gray-200 pb-5 sm:flex-row sm:items-center sm:gap-0">
        <h1 className="mb-3 font-bold text-5xl text-gray-900">My Files</h1>

        <UploadButton />
      </div>

      {/* Display All User Files */}
      {files && files?.length !== 0 ? (
        <div></div>
      ) : isLoading ? (
        <div></div>
      ) : (
        <div className="mt-16 flex flex-col items-center gap-2">
          <Ghost className="h-8 text-zinc-800" />
          <h3 className="font-semibold text-xl">
            Let&apos;s upload your first PDF.
          </h3>
        </div>
      )}
    </main>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 2):

Making the nextJS component, a client component worked for me.
You can do that by adding

```js
"use client";
```

at the top of your file.

Comment: I already added "use client" in all my components but still encountered the same problem, do you have any other suggestions, I've been dealing with this problem for days and still can't find any solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).